# Is there a program for creating and testing (spoofing) REST web services?

Tags: web-services, rest

I have a few REST Web Services I need to test and I am just wondering if there is a program out there for creating REST requests simply and viewing the response.  For example, a program where you enter the url and POST parameters and hit send to see the response?

I have been doing this via code, but I figured there may be an easier solution out there - if not, I might have to write one up!  Thank you.

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: I actually ended up using Chrome Poster add-on - super simple: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) for low-level HTTP access
- [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) has REST support
- [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) add-on for Firefox

Answer (score 1):

try this out http://www.soapui.org/